# Verbose copying of complete folder deleting target

Tags: rsync, deployment

I want to copy a development folder that has some changes into the server folder with `rsync`. Without rsync I would do it like

```
rm -Rf /var/www/site
cp -a dev /var/www/
```

But I would like to use `rsync`, so I can see the changed files while copying.

Answer (score 1):

Source: http://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/

> If a file or directory not exist at the source, but already exists at
>   the destination, you might want to delete that existing file/directory
>   at the target while syncing .
>
> We can use ‘--delete‘ option to delete files that are not there in
>   source directory.

So this will be the solution:

```
rsynv -av --delete dev/ /var/www/
```

see http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync+-avz+--delete